# An efficient way to check whether a polynomial (under certain condition) is absolutely equal to zero or not

Tags: number-theory, linear-algebra, algorithms, polynomials, computer-science

We have a function $f$ of $N$ variables which is the product of $M$ polynomials:
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_N) = P_1 \cdot P_2 \cdots  P_M.$$

Each $P_i$ is a polynomial of at most three variables ($x_j$s) with degree 1, and each variable appears in at most two of the $P_i$ 's, so the highest degree of each variable in $f$ is limited by $2$.
Now, the question is that if we expand $f$ and then replace every $x_i^2$ with $x_i$, would the result be absolute zero or not? in other words:
$$g(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_N) = f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_N) \bmod (x_1^2-x_1) \bmod (x_2^2-x_2) \cdots \bmod (x_N^2-x_N)$$
is $g == 0$ or not ? (by $\bmod$ I mean polynomial remainder)

Example:

- $f = (x+y - 2xy)(y+z - 2yz)(z+x - 2zx)$.
- $g = \mathrm{remainder}(\mathrm{remainder}(\mathrm{remainder}(f , x^2-x), y^2-y), z^2-z) == 0$.

i.e. if we expand f, and then replace every $x^2$ by $x$ , $y^2$ by $y$, and $z^2$ by $z$, all the terms will cancel out and the result will be absolute zero.

The challenge is that, expanding $f$ may result in an exponential number of intermediate terms, so I'm looking for an algorithm that can test whether $g==0$ without the need to fully expand $f$. For example by assigning some numerical values to $x_i$ and evaluating $f$ or through some transformation that can simplify calculation of $g$.

---

EDIT: a newer version of this question is now posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708282)

Comment: It is obvious that $g\equiv 0$ iff $\forall (x_1,...,x_n)\in \{0,1\}^n\; (f(x_1,...x_n)=0.)$ This requires evaluating $f$ at  $2^n$ points.   There  are extra constraints on $f$  and clearly you want to know if that  can allow us to do better than $O(2^n)$ calculations...... I dk.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet correct. In the other version of the problem which is equivalent, you can replace all $x^2$ with 1 (and if you wanted then replace all $x$'s by zero). And we want to know if it will be equal to zero or not at the end of this simplification. This is also equivalent to checking whether or not the coefficient of $x_1 x_2 ... x_n$ term is zero (without the need for any other manipulation or remaindering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) with the additional requirement that every variable appear in at most two clauses. This is dealt with in a [paper](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.113.3236%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dps&rct=j&q=fanout%20limitations%20on%20constraint%20systems&ei=cWlbTaChKImUtweMg5CfDA&usg=AFQjCNG1c6Rln6D4rZZS48SyOnsLutelaA&cad=rja) by Feder and another [paper](http://www.dtic.upf.edu/%7Evdalmau/mfcs6.ps.gz) by Dalmau and Ford.

If you really allow all possible clauses involving three variables, then you can encode 3SAT, as Feder shows: if a variable $x$ is used $n$ times, replace every use of it by $x_i$, and add consistency clauses:
$$ (x_1=x_2=y_1) \land (y_1=x_3=y_2) \land (y_2=x_4=y_3) \land \cdots \land (y_{n-3} = x_{n-1} = x_n). $$

Feder and Dalmau and Ford are trying to characterize the restrictions on the clauses which result in polytime-solvable problems; the latter (attributing the result to the former) have shown that if every variable is allowed to occur three times, then the problem is always NP-complete. Related work is [Schaefer](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ccs.neu.edu%2Fhome%2Flieber%2Fcourses%2Fcsg260%2Ff06%2Fmaterials%2Fpapers%2Fmax-sat%2Fp216-schaefer.pdf&rct=j&q=schaeffer%20the%20complexity%20of%20sati&ei=bWxbTeZvgvjwBtb-2bQO&usg=AFQjCNG_f2JcF9lMFLruW8u5IBJGSiMSBA&cad=rja) which does just that without the "maximum-use" constraint, and [Kratochvíl](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.acm.org%2Fcitation.cfm%3Fid%3D152385&rct=j&q=kratochvil%20One%20more%20occurrence%20of%20variables%20makes%20satisfiability%20jump%20from%20trivial%20to%20np-complete&ei=3mdbTbm9HpSgtwfZm42DDA&usg=AFQjCNHWuHNQOVTdwXm8b0cZw3SpUR9ogQ&cad=rja) which shows that for $k$-SAT, there is a jump from polytime-solvable to NP-complete, depending on the allowed number of occurrences (I'm not sure whether they give the exact number).

Comment: On the positive side, you can encode the problem as a SAT instance and then use a SAT solver (some of them perhaps accept CSPs directly).