# solving $ f(x,y,z) = \beta_{111} x y z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, computational-complexity

We have a polynomial in three variables with maximum degree of 2 for each variable:

$f(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=0}^{2} \sum_{j=0}^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2} \beta_{ijk}  x^i y^j z^k$

We could separate terms with different powers of $x$ and rewrite $f$ as following:

$f(x,y,z) = a_{x,0} + a_{x,1} x + a_{x,2} x^2$

where $a_{x,0}, a_{x,1}, a_{x,2}$ are polynomials in $y,z$. This could be done similarly for $y$ and $z$.

1) Under what conditions (for what class of functions $f$), does there exist a solution to the following system of equations ?

$ a_{x,0} + a_{x,2} x^2 =0 $

$  a_{y,0} + a_{y,2} y^2 =0 $

$  a_{z,0} + a_{z,2} z^2 =0 $

$  f(x,y,z) = \beta_{111} x y z$

Here is an example $f$ for which there exist a solution:

$f = (1-x y) (1+x+z-x z) (1-y z) = 1+x-x y-x^2 y+z-x z-y z  \mathbf{-2}  x y z+x^2 y z+x y^2 z+x^2 y^2 z-y z^2+x y z^2+x y^2 z^2-x^2 y^2 z^2$

Then the following is a solution:

$ x=0$, $y=1$, and $z=-1$

another solution is:

$x=0.214413$, $y=2.41421$,  $z=-0.800199$

one could verify that for both of these solutions, $f(x,y,z)=\beta_{111}xyz=-2xyz$

Here is another example for which no solutions exist: $f(x,y,z) = 5x-2xyz+1$ .There is obviously no solutions for the system:$1+0x^2=0, (1+5x)+0y^2=0,(1+5x)+0z^2=0,5x-2xyz+1=-2xyz $

2) (bonus) what if we are only interested in solutions where $xyz \neq 0$

3) (bonus) what if instead of 3 variables, we had $n$ variables ?

---

**EDIT:** solutions to the case $n=2$, i.e. only two variables would also be of interest!

A little bit of background: I am trying to develop an algorithm to check the coefficient for $x_1 x_2 ... x_n$ in a polynomial (which is given as product of several lower order polynomials such as the one in the example). More formally, we want to check whether $\beta_{11...1} = \frac{\partial^n }{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 ... \partial x_n}   f \bigg|_{x_1=x_2=...=x_n=0}$ is equal to zero or not. In general this is an NP hard problem. However, I am interested in the class of such polynomials where this could be checked efficiently. For example if a nonzero solution to the above system of equations exist, one could solve the first $n$ equations numerically, and then find $\beta_{11..1}= \frac{f({x_1}^*,{x_2}^*,...,{x_n}^*)}{{x_1}^*{x_2}^*...{x_n}^*}$. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2717134) for more background and proof for complexity of the general case).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some effort for solution to the case $n=2$

$ a_{x,0} + a_{x,2} x^2 =0 $

$  a_{y,0} + a_{y,2} y^2 =0 $

$  f(x,y) = \beta_{11} x y$

We could rewrite these three equations as following:

$ f(x,y) = x (\beta_{10}+\beta_{11}y+\beta_{12}y^2)$

$ f(x,y) = y (\beta_{01}+\beta_{11}x+\beta_{21}x^2)$

$ f(x,y) = \beta_{11} x y $

Subtracting the third equation from the first two we have:

$ x (\beta_{10}+\beta_{12}y^2) = y (\beta_{01}+\beta_{21}x^2) =0 $

Comparing these two equations with the first two equations, it is not hard to see that if $f$ is separable (i.e. $f = f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2) ... f_n(x_n)$), then the two sets would be equivalent.